# Javascript playing sound results in "Error calling method on NPObject"

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to play a sound in my javascript file

```
document.getElementById("sound").innerHTML = "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" id=\"beep\" loop=\"false\" />";
thissound=document.getElementById('beep');
thissound.Play();
```

but the `thissound.Play()` line gives me the error "Error calling method on NPObject"

Furthermore, if I add an `alert("Played sound!")` line right before the `thissound.Play()` line, there is no error and it works fine!

What is the problem with this? The sound does play, but then the program freezes.

Comment: If the alert maybe makes it work, might be the fact you are calling the Play too soon before the file is fully loaded?

Comment: I see. so how could I ensure the file is fully loaded before playing the sound?

Comment: Shouldn't `autostart=true` play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be not pretty. If it is hard to detect when the sound is fully loaded, you can keep trying playing the sound until it works.

```
var error = true;

while(error) {
    try {
        error = false;
        thissound.play();
    }
    catch (e) {
        error = true;
    }
}
```